# Using Redux's store.getState() and store.dispatch() to make changes without subscribing in React?

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I watched the Getting Started with Redux series and am working through modifying my existing React code to use Redux. However, I've run into a dilemma that I can't seem to find any answers for: I want to modify the store data (which many of my React components will use) on particular events such UI interaction, but I don't want any UI components to subscribe to every change made to the store.

Can/should I instead make a separate .js file with functions that can access the store directly to call .getState() and .dispatch() which my UI components can import and call when needed, instead of subscribing to the store themselves?

Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something and subscribing to the store would have exactly the same effect? I'm aiming to optimize speed; that's why I switched to Redux.

Comment: You shouldn't connect all the granular components to the store. Only the top level components should be the connected components, and you can pass the data as prop to the child components. And if you don't want your child components to be updated with the change in props, then you can use shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to modify the store data (which many of my React components
>   will use) on particular events such UI interaction, but I don't want
>   any UI components to subscribe to every change made to the store.

Checkout [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux), it's the official binding for react and redux apps. It provides a way to subscribe specific components to redux and only listen for the changes that you are interested in. On top of that it also implements various optimisations to avoid unnecessary re-renders.

> Can/should I instead make a separate .js file with functions that can
>   access the store directly to call .getState() and .dispatch() which my
>   UI components can import and call when needed, instead of subscribing
>   to the store themselves?

You can do anything you like, but don't be surprised if it becomes unmaintainable after a while.

> Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something and subscribing to
>   the store would have exactly the same effect?

Yes, you could use react-redux and only subscribe to parts of the store that you care about.

> I'm aiming to optimize speed; that's why I switched to Redux.

Not sure what your particular situation is / was, but in general the point of redux is to provide a predictable and manageable way of maintaining an applications state - it doesn't directly speed up anything.